# Tokbox camera filter API not working when changing browser tab

Tags: javascript, stream, youtube-api, video-streaming, tokbox

Tokbox camera filter API has an issue when I change my browser tab it remove video stream and add video stream when I come back on same tab.

Also, I am using youtube broadcast so when I change my browser tab it will display blank screen on youtube.

Demo link: https://aullman.github.io/opentok-camera-filters/

Comment: If I switch my browser tab then it will display a black screen on other publishers on same session for my stream.